# Can't upgrade Scipy 1.5.4 to 1.7.0 using pip

Tags: python, pip

I am a new Ubuntu user and don't have much experience with how installations are done in Linux. I installed the Scipy module using pip a while ago and it downloaded version 1.5.4.
Now, when I try to upgrade it to version 1.7.0 using pip, it cannot seem to find the package to download and says the latest version is already installed. I have tried finding for alternate ways to install the latest version but they are too complicated for me to follow without a thorough understanding of how linux works. Is there a simple way to upgrade Scipy on linux?

Answer (score 0):

try,

`pip uninstall scipy`

`pip install scipy`